# Meaning Of Limits

Tags: real-analysis

What does it mean to say that $x \to c$? Is it meaningless unless it is associated with the behaviour of the function $f(x)$ near $c$? If not then please explain the meaning of $x \to c$.

Comment: This is a useful notation to hide some $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, and have a more intuitive notation for limits. For example, we may say that "a function $f$ is continuous at $c$ if $f(x)\to f(c)$ when $x\to c$". The formal definition would be "a function $f$ is continuous at $c$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$, for some $\delta$ depending only on $\epsilon$".

Comment: No my question is does $x \to c$ has some meaning or not here do not consider any function or any other thing

Comment: Yes, it does, but it is more abstract. First, we introduce the "$x_i\to y$" notation for [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). Then given a topological space $X$ and $c\in X$, we consider the directed set $\Delta=\left\{(x,U):x\in U\text{ and }y\in\operatorname{int}(U)\right\}$, preordered by reverse set inclusion. The notation "$x\to c$" means that the net $\Delta\to X$, $(x,U)\mapsto x$ converges to $c$.